# Lie derivative and simultaneous diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, differential-geometry

I just arrived at this theorem:

> Let $M$ be an $n$-manifold and let  $\{X_j\}_{j\le k}$ be a collecion of $k$ vector fields 
>   and $p \in V \subset M$ satisfying:
>
> 1) $\{X_j(p)\}_{j\le k}$ is linearly independent
>
> 2) $[X_j,X_i]_a = 0$ for all $a$ in $V$.
>
> $\implies$ There exists a chart $(x,U)$ with $U \subset V$ that satisfies
>   $X_i=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ for all $i \le k$

The analogy with simultaneously diagonalizable operators (iff commuting) seems very strong.
Is there a deep algebraic result behind this?

Comment: I can guess what you mean but it would help if you placed quantifiers for $p$ and $q$.

Comment: I don't understand the analogy.